# Regex: replace &amp; and , . : / - _

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

At the moment I have no idea how to solve my problem?
I want to replace those chars with a space:

```
$replaceSpace = ["-", "–", "_", "/"];
```

And those with a "" (Nothing/Delete):

```
$replaceNothing = [":", ",", ";", "`", "#", "'", "´", "–", "!", "(", ")", ".", "@", "’", "+", "™"];
```

How can I do that? - And that also if they are between words or if they stand alone!

Greetings :)

Comment: And I forgot. I also want to replace &amp; with an & and make space bevor and behind the &. How can I do that?

Comment: Your question is very unclear and is too broad. Please show your attempts and try to elaborate more on it.

Comment: @sidyll Why do you assume OP is using PHP?

Comment: @MarounMaroun It was tagged, wasn't it? Am I going crazy here? LOL

Comment: It is PHP... I forgot to say it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Example:

```
// Outputs F because A is replaced with B, then B is replaced with C, and so on...
// Finally E is replaced with F, because of left to right replacements.
$search  = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
$replace = array('B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');
$subject = 'A';
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
```

So in your case it would be:

```
$subject = "sth-sth-sth";
$replaceSpace = ["-", "–", "_", "/"];
echo str_replace($replaceSpace, " ", $subject);
```